# Can't seem to overwrite IE11 print margin

Tags: css, printing

I'm working on a print page, which teases me a Little. I can't seem to overwrite IE11 default page settings, when I print a specific page.

Maybe it can't be done, but from what I have Googled and understand, is should be possible.

I have this style:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {

@page Section1{ 
size:21.0cm 29.7cm;
margin:1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm;
}
<!--@page { margin-left: 1cm; margin-right:1cm; margin-top:1cm; margin-bottom:1cm; }-->
@page :header { content: none ;} 
@page :footer { content: none ;} 
}

div.Section1 {
page:Section1;
}

body, td {
margin: 0px;
color:#000000;
background:#FFFFFF;

}
h1 {
font-size: 16pt;
}
.header {
font-size: 10pt;
font-weight: bold;
}
.header2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align:center;
}
.total {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align:center;
}
.total_right {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align:right;
}

.noborder {
text-align:center;
border:none;    
}
.text {
  text-align:center;
}

.text_right {
  text-align:right;
}
.text_left {
  text-align:left;
}
.onlytopcenter {
border-top-color:#000000;
border-bottom:none;
border-left:none;
border-right:none;
text-align:center
}

td {
border: solid 1px;
border-color:#CCCCCC;
padding:1px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 7pt;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

</style>
```

and calling it with this on my content:

```
<div class="Section1">
<table>
...
...
</table>
</div>
```

When I print the page, I keep getting the default margins on 19,05 mm (I think). I can change it manually, but that is no-go for at system used by many users. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The only think you are doing wrong is using IE.
I was having the same troubles, then I find out that using @page inside @media query doesnt work in IE for some reason. Removing @page from inside @media and putting it directly helped.

```
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 4mm;
}
@page :header { content: none ;} 
@page :footer { content: none ;}
```

Now IE sets margin for print correctly.